# Print data to the Zebra printer which is over network

Tags: c#, asp.net

Print data to the Zebra printer which is over network. There are no errors, but the document which has not been printed.

string ipAddress = "10.38.xxx.xx";
            int port = 9100;

```
        // ZPL Command(s)
        string ZPLString =
         "^XA" +
         "^FO50,50" +
         "^A0N50,50" +
         "^FDHello, World!^FS" +
         "^XZ";

        try
        {
            // Open connection
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

            // Write ZPL String to connection
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            writer.Write(ZPLString);
            writer.Flush();

            // Close Connection
            writer.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Catch Exception
        }
```

Comment: If you remove the try-catch, do then get an error message?

Comment: Does the documment appears on the Printer Spool of the Zebra Printer?

Comment: I cannot test this at this moment, I've have no Zebra at home.
May you try this? 

writer.Write(ZPLString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) or even in ASCII encoding.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I will do that

Comment: Thanks David, unable to verify it, because there is no printer name to view it. I have used the IP and port to telnet that in the cmd. It is printing but using the asp.net using c# the data has not printed.

Comment: Thanks David, I will check it the one you mentioned

Comment: If you have the IP then you can add the printer to your PC as a network printer. Then you  can open the printer spool to verify if sended work is on the queue.